# Converting numbers to a string number

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(num1,num2,num3){
    var result ="";
    var sum = 0;

    sum = (num1*num2*num3);

    for(var i =sum; i > 0; i--){
        var str = i.toString();
        console.log(str);

        for(var j=0; j<str.length;j++){
            result = str[j] + result;
        }

        if(result === str){
           return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert the number from the first for loop so i can use the same number in the second for loop as a string. because I want to access the index of the number. for instance, 
var str = "1234";
str[0] = 1;
but, when the second loop runs, it will return unrelated output
does anyone know how to fix it ? please

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean, but I think perhaps you are confused about the output of the console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var num = 123; // The value of num is 123 - this is a number
var sum = num.toString(); // The value of sum is "123" - this is a string

console.log(num) // This logs 123 - this is a number
console.log(sum) // This logs "123" - this is a string

sum.length // This logs 3
```

Comment: I wanted to convert the number to a string so that the seance for loop can treat the number as a string because I want to be able to access the number such as, "1234".length = 4 but, 1234.length = 1;

Comment: If you want to convert it to a string, just call toString on it, that call will return a string.